# Euclidean norms in quadratic fields

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

I'm currently reading a set of lecture notes of Number Theory, and there's a small part I'm having trouble understanding.

> A norm $N: R  \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ is Euclidean if it satisfies: for all $a \in R, >b \in R $, there exists $q, r \in R$ such that $a = qb + r$ and $N(r) < N(b)$.

> Consider the norm given by $N(a + b \sqrt{D}) = |a^2 - Db^2| $

> Now, we consider the quadratic field $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$: to show that this is a Euclidean norm, we must show that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ there exists  $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-1})  $ with $N( \alpha - \beta ) < 1 $

*My question is*: **Why** is $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$  if we are considering $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]?$

For the notes I'm using, see: [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/4400quadrings.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400quadrings.pdf) page 5.

Comment: Is that really all your notes say? I'd expect a bit more proof here.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I added a link.

Answer (score 2):

@ChrisEagle is right, something's missing.

You are trying to do Euclidean division in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. So you take $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$, with $b \ne 0$, and consider $\alpha = a b^{-1} \in \Bbb{Q}(i)$, as $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ is a field.

If you can find a $\beta \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$ such that $N(\alpha - \beta) < 1$ (**PS** and you can indeed), then
$$
\alpha = a b^{-1} = \beta + (\alpha - \beta)
$$
so that, multiplying by $b$,
$$
a = b \beta + r
\tag{div}
$$
where $r = (\alpha - \beta) b = a - b \beta \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$, as $a, b, \beta \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$. Moreover,
$$
N(r) = N((\alpha - \beta) b) = N(\alpha - \beta)  \cdot N(b) < N(b), 
$$
so $r$ is the remainder, and in (div) you've just done Euclidean division.